# Convert SQL logic to Performant LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a collection of fields that represent rows in an excel document and I am attempting to speed up the processing of a few LINQ statements. I can easily express the solution using SQL, however, I am struggling with a LINQ solution that is performant. Here is the query I wrote to demonstrate the problem.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(RowNumber INT, FieldName NVARCHAR(25), FieldValue NVARCHAR(25))
INSERT @T( RowNumber, FieldName, FieldValue ) VALUES
(1,'F1','100'),(1,'F2','A'),(1,'F3','A'),
(2,'F1','200'),(2,'F2','A'),(2,'F3','A'),
(3,'F1','300'),(3,'F2','A'),(3,'F3','A'),
(4,'F1','400'),(4,'F2','A'),(4,'F3','A'),
(5,'F1','100'),(5,'F2','B'),(5,'F3','B'),
(6,'F1','100'),(6,'F2','C'),(6,'F3','B'),
(7,'F1','200'),(7,'F2','B'),(7,'F3','B'),
(8,'F1','100'),(8,'F2','A'),(8,'F3','A'),
(9,'F1','100'),(9,'F2','A'),(9,'F3','A'),
(10,'F1','400'),(10,'F2','A'),(10,'F3','A')

;WITH Flattended AS
(
    SELECT
            RowNumber,
            F1=MAX(F1),
            F2=MAX(F2),
            F3=MAX(F3)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                RowNumber,
                F1=CASE WHEN FieldName='F1' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END,
                F2=CASE WHEN FieldName='F2' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END,
                F3=CASE WHEN FieldName='F3' THEN FieldValue ELSE NULL END
            FROM  @T 
        )
        AS A
        GROUP BY RowNumber
),
FlattenedGrouped AS
(
    SELECT F1, F2, F3
    FROM Flattended
    GROUP BY F1,F2,F3
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Flattended F 
    INNER JOIN FlattenedGrouped FG ON FG.F1=F.F1 AND FG.F2=F.F2 AND FG.F3=F.F3
```

In real life the collection looks like the following :

```
public class Cell
{
   public int RowNumber;
   public string ColumnName;
   public string ColumnValue;
}

public class ThisThing
{
    public List<Cell> Cells;
}
```

I need to find all Cell RowNumbers where the Cell FieldNames include 'F1', 'F2' and 'F3' and the values for F1, F2 and F3 match at least one other cell.

In excel this scenario below, RowNumber 1 and 10 would be returned.

```
 RowNumber  F1  F2  F3
       1    100 A   A
       2    200 A   A
       3    300 A   A
       4    400 A   A
       5    500 A   A
       6    100 A   B
       7    600 A   A
       8    700 A   A
       9    800 A   A
      10    100 A   A
```

Here is the linq that I am working on:

```
var _allFirstFieldMatches = properties.Where(p => p.Column == "F1").ToList()
            .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
            .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                RowNumber = p.Min(o => o.RowNumber),
                F1 = p.Min(o => o.Value)
            });

       var _allFirstAndSecondFieldMatches = properties
        .Where(p => p.Column == "F2" && _allFirstFieldMatches.Any(p1 => p1.RowNumber == p.RowNumber)).ToList()
        .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
        .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            RowNumber = p.Min(o => o.RowNumber),
            F2 = p.Min(o => o.Value)
        });

       var _allFirstAndSecondAndThirsFieldMatches = properties
       .Where(p => p.Column == "F3" && _allFirstAndSecondFieldMatches.Any(p1 => p1.RowNumber == p.RowNumber)).ToList()
       .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
       .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)
       .Select(p => new
       {
           RowNumber = p.Min(o => o.RowNumber),
           F3 = p.Min(o => o.Value)
       });
```

Second Attempt:

```
   var _field1Duplicates = (from o in properties
                            where o.Column.Equals("F1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                            group o by o.Value into g
                            select new
                            {
                                DuplicateCount = g.Count(),
                                Value = g.Key
                            })
                            .ToList().Where(p => p.DuplicateCount > 1);


    var _dupField1Objects = (from o in properties
                             where o.Column.Equals("F2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
                             join b in _field1Duplicates on o.Value equals b.Value
                             select new
                             {
                                RowNumber = o.RowNumber,
                                F1 = o.Value,
                                F2 = properties.Where(p => p.RowNumber == o.RowNumber && p.Column == "F2").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                                F3 = properties.Where(p => p.RowNumber == o.RowNumber && p.Column == "F3").FirstOrDefault().Value
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: "I can easily express the solution using SQL, however, I am struggling with a LINQ solution that is performant" - then... use the SQL? LINQ isn't the answer to everything

Comment: Can you show some LINQ you tried that doesn't work well? For `FieldNames` did you mean `ColumnName`? By "`FieldName`s include" did you mean equals one of?

Comment: @MarcGravell - The code needs to be service layer code. The operation is in application memory.

Comment: @RossBush I don't see how that changes anything...

Comment: @MarcGravell - It is out of my hands. The solution has already been architected.

Comment: @NewMage - I have added what I would think is a correct route.

Comment: So you basically need a simple join? Rows where F1 F2 and F3 are all equal? And what's a point in those max/min if all you need are row numbers?

Comment: @Evk - I have updated my original attempt with a second stab, however, I feel it is terrible inefficient with the second and third lookup into the list. It yields a anon type with all F1 matches and the F2 and F3 values. I cant figure out how to do an "Anti" DISTINCT in linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate your SQL query almost literally to LINQ:

```
// building data
var source = new ThisThing() { Cells = new List<Cell>() };
var f1 = new[] { "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "100", "600", "700", "800", "100" };
var f2 = new[] { "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A" };
var f3 = new[] { "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A" };
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    source.Cells.Add(new Cell() { RowNumber = i, ColumnName = "F1", ColumnValue = f1[i - 1] });
    source.Cells.Add(new Cell() { RowNumber = i, ColumnName = "F2", ColumnValue = f2[i - 1] });
    source.Cells.Add(new Cell() { RowNumber = i, ColumnName = "F3", ColumnValue = f3[i - 1] });
}
// normalize, same as in SQL query
// note we do not materialize query yet
var normalized = source.Cells.Select(c => new {
    c.RowNumber,
    F1 = c.ColumnName == "F1" ? c.ColumnValue : null,
    F2 = c.ColumnName == "F2" ? c.ColumnValue : null,
    F3 = c.ColumnName == "F3" ? c.ColumnValue : null
});
// flatten, again literal transaction
// still query is not executed
var flattened = normalized.GroupBy(c => c.RowNumber).Select(c => new {
    RowNumber = c.Key,
    F1 = c.Max(r => r.F1),
    F2 = c.Max(r => r.F2),
    F3 = c.Max(r => r.F3),
});
// again almost literal transaction
// at the end, query is finally executed with ToArray()
var result = flattened
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.F1, c.F2, c.F3 })
    .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Select(r => r.RowNumber)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more. Is there a Linq construct that allows you to bail out if an aggregate reaches a threshold value? In the case above the duplicates translate to errors and once 100 errors are reached I would like to bailout. I am doubting this is possible but I thought I would ask. BTW, the above linq runs over ~50K records in under 3 seconds!

Comment: @RossBush yes, just add `Take(200)` before `ToArray()`. 200 because duplicate is 2 rows. As for perfomance - I tested on 100K rows with random data and it took 300ms on my machine.